# Supermicro X8DTU-F repeated reboot

Tags: supermicro, reboot

i have a Supermicro E5520 with MB=X8DTU-F. the server will not boot successfully either thru it's local HDD or a bootable CD/DVD/USB. When selected the CD/DVD to boot I can see a line for Linux (using a ESX 6.0 Live CD) and then the server reboots. When selected to boot off the local HDD it does the same. I also tried booting it off USB that contains bootable Puppy linux image but it also behaves the same way. I disabled the Watchdog (thru BIOS and not jumpers on MB) with no joy. It almost sounds like not enough power to drive the system full on?? no alarms/events with the 2x PSU in use.
any help is appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: This is quite an old motherboard. It may simply have failed. My first step would be to try other memory, and then another power supply. Use one PSU at a time.

Comment: Thanks Wurtel. As you said,i installed every RAM in a sequence until i could recreate the issue.What i noticed is the "BLUE" colored memory slots wouldn't recognise the new RAM i had bought.Rather,i installed the legacy RAM chip in those slots. it seems the PSU's are OK. At least now i can boot from CD/USB. Thanks again for help.